# Do refunded in-app purchase subscriptions show as expired?

Tags: iphone, ios, in-app-purchase

When validating an in-app purchase with Apple servers, if the user has received a refund, do the expires_date and status code reflect the cancellation?

I would expect a status code of 21006 (expired) and an expiration date in the past.

[Relevant Apple docs are here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/RenewableSubscriptions/RenewableSubscriptions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH4-SW5).

There's a [related question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6439482/how-does-apple-notify-ios-apps-of-refunds-of-in-app-purchases-iap), asking about whether Apple will provide explicit notification of refunds.  I know they don't, but it could be inferred if a subscription expired early.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's  better to contact apple support.

Answer (score 0):

I have yet to test this, but I have it on very good authority that when a refund occurs, the receipt will show up as expired on subsequent validation.  Will update with confirmation.

Comment: Very curious if this is true!  Please update