# How to cancel or refund purchased consumable In-App purchase in iOS?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I want to know that how we can cancel or refund a purchased In-App product (Consumable) in iOS. Do we have any way to do that?

Comment: now way, customer must contact to Apple to refund.You can only implement "restore purchase" for non-consumable item in case they switch device or reinstall app/game on their device.

Comment: Thanks for negative marking... It helps me to stop asking questions.

Comment: @MohdHaider, your statement would be correct with this extension: _"It helps me to stop asking questions, **before I make essential research.**"_. (I'm not the downvoter anyway, but I was tempted.)

Comment: I know that we can restore non-consumable products and I also study all type of in-app purchasing but I wanted to clear my problem that I can cancel purchased consumable product or not by any way. Thanks for your time.

Comment: [How does Apple notify iOS apps of refunds of in-app purchases (IAP)?
](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6439482/6521116)

Answer (score 4):

This is not currently possible.

Canceling or refunding In-App Purchases is something that is done on Apple's side and it is the duty of your users to contact Apple if there is an issue with refunding of any purchases.

If you insist on informing them somehow, consider adding a contact form to your application that gives instructions to your users on how to contact Apple with their request.

This isn't an issue that you should run into often: if it is, there's something wrong with the value you're putting into your IAPs and you might want to consider revising them.

Also check out the [technical note](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2259/_index.html) for In-App Purchases in Apple's documentation.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It clear the situation for me.