# Does Apple communicate with App Provider/Devs before providing refund to a customer for In-app purchases iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

If I am the App provider & developer, one thing I did understand about the refund process is that the user can directly ask Apple for a refund. Now my question is whether Apple asks the App provider/Devs for whether the refund should be made or does it decide on its own? If it does, then does my content still remain available to the user? I read another question that Apple doesn't notify the App of a refund. Also if I am not concerned with the refund process,because providing the content is my responsibility, how will I know if a product has been refunded or not so I may stop this to the user who has?

Comment: I think this may be off-topic because It's not a programming question, but a question about Apple's refund process.

Comment: Why would it be off-topic since I am to decide whether to provide my purchased content or not? This would have to be done programmatically in the app I believe.

Comment: I think this may have been answered already. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6439482/how-does-apple-notify-ios-apps-of-refunds-of-in-app-purchases-iap?rq=1

Comment: Yes, I did read that before asking, only thing I needed more was this whether Apple does the refund on its own decision or does it bother to ask the App provider?If such is the case, then is the app probably at loss because user still has my data and is getting a refund.