# Preventing iTunes refunds

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store, non-renewing-subscription

I have an exam preparation app which you purchase access to for specific periods of time. Some people have started canceling their purchases even though the subscription remains active in the app. I have used the "non renewing" IAP type. I know that when purchasing some in app purchases the user is warned that the purchase cannot be cancelled.

Can i opt in to this? Do i need to change the IAP type, or is it a code level issue?

Since access to the content is effective immediately after purchasing, i believe the user should have no right to getting a refund? We have a 24 hour trial period so they know what they are getting.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about Apple App Store policies, not programming

Comment: How is it not about programming if you perhaps enable this in code? I don't know which is why I'm asking.

Comment: Apple customer support can issue refunds. There is nothing you can do in code about it.

Comment: i believe the user should have no right to getting a refund? - you can believe whatever you like. Its up to apple to make refund decisions. Don't like it then make app a paid app not a freemium and even then a user can request a refund.

Comment: I didn't ask for your opinions about who's decision it should be about a refund. The reality is that Apple sometimes pops up alerts about not being able to get a purchase refunded - i want that. I cannot make the app paid because it uses a subscription model.

Comment: You can't prevent refunds, but you might be able to detect they are canceled. This answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/21124208/449161 suggests you can look for a cancelation date in the receipt -- though you would presumably have to refresh the receipt for this to happen, which might prompt the user for their credentials. This may be something you just have to live with.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @BenFlynn that sure looks interesting. Isn't it possible to retrieve receipts on iOS 8+ without password prompts? Iirc they changed a lot with receipts recently. If you write it in an answer i will accept it as we can use that info the cancel the users account in our own system (since we're multi platform).