# In-App Purchase cancellation notification is not received

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase, xcode9

I've implemented In-App Purchase for one of my application. In this application, We have used Auto - Renewable subscription.

The issue is happening right now that we’re not getting notification from Apple about cancellation that if any subscription get cancelled.

I’ve tried to contact apple several time but in response they’ve shared guides with me. I have looked for the guide and checked out with in app and server configuration as well but seems all details are OK and working fine.

The server which has been used is VPS.

Does any one has faced this issue previously and can help me to solve this because the app is live on store?

Comment: Hey Nij, You can look at this  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6439482/how-does-apple-notify-ios-apps-of-refunds-of-in-app-purchases-iap